# Blank screen between windows 8.1 logo and login screen. .

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, login-screen, blank-screen

I have been using windows 8.1. Some days ago i encountered an issue that after login screen i was facing a black screen on my laptop for about 10 seconds (varying). I tried too much to check what is problem with it by checking and disabling startup items and services but i could not find solution. Someone suggested that there may be issue regarding graphic driver as it may be adjusting resolution. But i am having same system, same windows and same graphics drivers that were working great. I somehow reinstalled and updated graphics drivers but issue remained still. Disabled all startup items but in vain. So finally i reinstalled windows after too much searching and failing to find the solution.

Problem was solved upon reinstalling windows. I installed all the updates of graphics and was also installing windows updates from time to time as they downloaded. Form yesterday i am getting same issue again. I am suspicious that some windows update has caused this issue again because i have not installed any program during last complete day but installing windows updates was in progress. If this was the problem, then still i will be unable to find which update caused the problem because about 20 updates i installed yesterday as of Patch Tuesday from Microsoft.

Can anyone please help me regarding this.

System: Corei3
RAM: 6GB

Comment: What graphics card? Which driver version?

Comment: AMD ATI Radeon HD 5650, latest version donwloaded from ATI Website